# Confused about how to properly use secret keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, stripe-payments

So in my quest to get Stripe integrated, I find myself confused about how to properly use secret keys and environmental variables. To my understanding, I do NOT want to explicitly include my secret key in any public place and should be using a environmental variable instead. But it does not seem to work when I substitute the ENV in place of the actual hardcoded key. I am doing something wrong, but what? Here is what I have. In my secret.yml file:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  secret_key: sk_test_JlKC4V7nmCQ0sE4iNAVyoAxA
  publishable_key: pk_test_KfCg1YmVXwBYyEdPEWnfibF8

  stripe_live_publishable_key: pk_live_pxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  stripe_live_secret_key: sk_live_jxxxxxxxxxxxxx

test:
  secret_key_base: a38exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
#test
  secret_key: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY"] %>
  publishable_key: <%= ENV["PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>
# live
  stripe_live_publishable_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_LIVE_PRODUCTION_KEY"] %>
  stripe_live_secret_key: <%= ENV["STRIPE_LIVE_SECRET_KEY"] %>
```

and in /initialize/stripe.rb I have:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
   :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
   :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

 Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

and in my payment form, I have the line:
`Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= 'sk_test_JlKC4V7nmCQ0sE4iNAVyoAxA'%>');`

It works like this, but unless I am misunderstanding, is insecure (well, right now it is just a test key, but I need to know this when I use live keys for production). Yet when I try to use:

`Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>');`

I get the error:
`Uncaught Error: You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key.`

or when I try:

`Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= :publishable_key %>');`

I get an error `401 (Unauthorized)` in console.

How am I supposed yo be using the ENV[KEY] so that I do not need my key written out in plain sight?

**UPDATE:**
Here is my form where the key would be most public:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Contribution Form</title>

  <!-- The required Stripe lib -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

  <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'); //<====How should this line look?

    var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');

      if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    };

    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()}, stripeResponseHandler);

        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<!--  form -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row Row one">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
        <h1>Make your contribution</h1>
           <%= form_for @project, url: project_charges_path, :html => {:id => "payment-form"}, method: 'post' do |f| %>

                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :@project_id, :value => @project.id %>


                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %><br>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: ' card-number form-control', :required => true %><br>
                </div>

                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code (cvc)" %><br>
                  <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'card-cvc form-control', :required => true %><br>
                </div>

                <div class= "field">
                  <%= label_tag :card_month, "Expiration" %>
                  <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, class: "card-expiry-month"} %>
                  <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, class: "card-expiry-year"}%>
                </div>


                <div class= "field">
                    <%= label_tag :amount, "Amount" %><br>
                    <%= text_field_tag :amount %> 
                </div> 

                <div class= "field">
                    <%= label_tag :comments, "Add a comment?" %><br>
                    <%= text_area_tag :comments %> 
                </div>                 

                <div class= "actions">
                  <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'contribution-submit' %>
                </div>

          <div id="stripe_error">
              <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
          </div>

          <% end %> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="row"></div> -->
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables in production have more to do with the application server than  with your rails app.  To me it looks like everything you've done seems correct , just need to set the variables in production mode.

## For Heroku:

```
heroku config:set STRIPE_PERISHABLE_KEY=<your key here>
heroku config:set STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=<your key here>
```

## For Passenger (nginx or apache):

In your server/site definition with passenger you can add passenger environment variables.

```
passenger_env_var STRIPE_PERISHABLE_KEY '<your key here>';
passenger_env_var STRIPE_SECRET_KEY '<your key here>';
```

*Note that with Apache you use an = sign between the key and the value and there are no quotes around the value.

Comment: thanks for your answer! can you clarify which way is correct to reference the key in a public file? as I mentioned  `Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= 'sk_test_JlKC4V7nmCQ0sE4iNAVyoAxA'%>')`  works, but seems insecure. I expect yo be able to use ` Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>') ` or maybe `Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= :publishable_key %>')`

Comment: You've already done it the right way.  Your secrets.yml and your stripe initializer look as they should.  I think you're only missing the env variables in the prod env.

Comment: okay I am going to set those in terminal as you suggested then, thanks :)

Comment: How should I reference the key in the form? That is really what I am confused about. The form is public, and I do not want to reveal my key. I am going to update my question with the form, so you can better see what I am referring to.... In the meantime, I am going to set up the keys in terminal

Comment: You don't reveal keys in forms.  I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  You might take a look at the this tutorial.   It might give you a better start-to-finish stripe concept.  Best of luck::: http://stillriversoftware.com/blog/integrating-stripe-into-your-ruby-on-rails-app/

Comment: Thank you @stillriversoftware, that looks like it will be helpful!

Comment: @HolyMoly To address your concern that it seems insecure to expose your key in a form that is public; It is actually not an insecure practice. That is how a *public* key works. "The public key can be sent to anyone, and as long as the private key remains only in that user’s control, it’s secure." learn more here: http://workendtech.com/pgp-encryption-basic-overview/

Comment: thanks Bryan, it was all (and still is) new to me, working with keys. The support department from Stripe helped out and looked at this thread, and told me the same thing you just did. I thought all keys were top secret! Well now I know. lol. I will check out that reading, and I appreciate the resource and response! :)

Answer (score 0):

ENV variables are set via terminal. This isn't the 'best practice' but I set my keys in my .bash_profile. There are also gems that manage your env-vars for you.

Here is a popular one that implements yaml:

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Here is an example of adding keys to your .bash_profile

```
## Work Keys
export STRIPE_KEY="pk_test_somekey"
export STRIPE_SECRET="sk_test_somekey"
```

Then in ruby you can access the variable like this:

```
ENV["STRIPE_KEY"]
ENV["STRIPE_SECRET"]
```

You need to refresh your environment after doing this by making a new terminal instance. So quit terminal and restart your server!

Comment: So if I set them in terminal, would I need to do anything when I deploy to heroku and go into production mode? The Stripe docs say to set up these files as I have them, I am not sure why this is not working... I will do some more googling about setting env vars in terminal

Comment: In heroku you need to add them separately. You can do this on heroku.com. OR you can add them via terminal again. Like this: heroku config:set STRIPE_KEY=pk_test_somekey

Comment: cool, let me give that a whirl. Thanks!  Do you think I need to delete or mess with the files I already have? Will there be any conflicts? And if I do delete or alter them, since Stripe is expecting them, do you anticipate any conflicts in that???

Comment: Delete everything besides your stripe.rb. Remove all other places you wrote your keys.

Comment: so i removed the keys (actually i just commented them out) in the secret.yml file, I left the stripe.rb file alone, and I left the line that references the key in the form (it is needed there i think) alone as well, and it didn't work for me. I am not saying I did it correctly though, but i tried to. lol

Comment: Are you running the site locally or on heroku?

Comment: I have it locally, and also on Heroku. I want to configure it for a production environment, and re-push it to Heroku, as right now, the site breaks whenever somebody tries to make a payment (fake payment)